# Writing an equivilant expression in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I need to write an equivalent expression to this : 
$$\sum_{i = 0}^{15} \binom{20}{i}\binom{30}{15 - i}$$
I'm thinking about 
$$\binom{50}{15} \cdot 2^{15}$$
Am I even close ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: [Proper typesetting tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Learn it. Love it. Breathe it. Type it.

Comment: Will do, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

From 20 boys and 30 girls you are forming a team of 15 students.In how many ways can you form the team?

Comment: So using your hint, it's just 50 chooses 15, right ?

Comment: exactly! Read about van der monde identity

Comment: Great, thank you very much !